# if recursively find ext, then, else on unix

Tags: unix

This is what I normally use. But I need to recursively find an extension with, then, and else. The problem with this one is that it is not recursive.

```
if ls $HOME/Downloads/*.ext >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    :
else
    :
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` instead of ls. If you have GNU find, you can use `-quit` to exit after the first match. Then just check if it returned any result.

The script would look something like

```
if [ -n "$(find $HOME/Downloads -name '*.ext' -print -quit | head -n 1)" ]
then
    :
else
    :
fi
```

Use -iname instead of -name to do a case insensitive search.